# KSH Script won't correctly when ran via Crontab job

Tags: sql, linux, cron, ksh, aql

I have KSH script.

If I run it manually using `./scriptname.ksh` then it would work fine.

but if I set up a crontab job, I get error that AQL not found. (AQL is like SQL but not different).

**Here is my script code.**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

AQL << EOF
select count(*) from <tableT>;
exit
```

**Here is crontab -e**

```
12 13 * * * /usr/users/somedir/dir3/dir4/scriptname.ksh > /usr/users/somedir/dir3/dir4/testz.txt 2>&1
```

**Here is what crontab runs and outputs to testz.txt**

```
/usr/users/somedir/dir3/dir4/scriptname.ksh: line 9: AQL: not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AQL is probably not in the PATH for the environment the script executes in. Try using the fully qualified path to AQL (e.g. `/full/path/to/AQL`). In general, for this reason as well as for security, it's a good practice to specify fully qualified paths in scripts.

Comment: but I just realized the problem. I login to server as somedir user and  then only I can run AQL. I cannot run AQL as any other user. so when crontab tries to run AQL it won't recognize it. I tried this manually by logging in as root user. can you plz suggest a solution.

Comment: Put the cron job in the somedir user's crontab. Log in as root, use `crontab -e -u somdeir`, add the cron job and save it. And also give the fully qualified path as suggested in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion but I can't find the path to AQL. :( I am super new to this.

Comment: Try `find / -name AQL`

Comment: To find a program in ksh, do `whence -a AQL`

Comment: I was able to find the path, and it was able to start AQL but it is not working correctly. (I changed query to `select count(*) from tableT;` I get this error `unable to translate the acronym <tableT>
Abort message from process 11229, program "AQL":
 COMMON y1_ftok error: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Comment: btw it still work correctly if I manually run the script by using `./scriptname.ksh`

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding `su - somedir << EOF` before AQL command. Thanks all